# How to Realign a Horizontal Stack with the Above Item

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, horizontal, stackengine, stack

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight 8.25in \textwidth 4.75in
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

%\blacksquare\hspace*{.7em}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\difbox[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{\color{white}\rule{5ex}{1.15ex}}{%
    $\iftrue\makeballs#1\fi$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L} }
\def\makeballs#1#2\fi{\fi\ifx R#1\textcolor{red}{\blacksquare}\else
  \ifx B#1\textcolor{blue!35}{\blacksquare}\fi\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\makeballs#2\fi}
\newenvironment{benumerate}
{\renewcommand\item[1][1]{\def\difficulty{##1}\svitem}%
  \def\labelenumi{\smash{\stackunder[5pt]{\color{blue!65!black}%
  \bfseries\sffamily\theenumi}{\expandafter\difbox\expandafter{\difficulty}}}}%
  \enumerate}{\endenumerate}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{benumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\item[RBRRBR] \lipsum[11]
\item[RRR] \lipsum[39]
\item[BRRRB] \lipsum[13]
\end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

with output

[image]

I would like to widen the gap between the colored squares; but when I replace both instances of `\blacksquare` with `\blacksquare\hspace*{.7em}`---I get the extra spacing I want, but relative to the above enumeration, the new horizontal stack appears to be non-aligned; i.e., not lying centered beneath the above number, as follows:

[image]

Now, the alignment in the first output is not perfect, but reasonably accurate. However, the alignment in the second output is clearly not centered beneath the corresponding number.

QUESTION: How may I increase the gap between the colored boxes of the original output so that the horizontal stack of colored squares lies reasonably centered below the upper number?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\unskip` at the end to remove the trailing space that is causing the offset:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight 8.25in \textwidth 4.75in
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,lipsum}
\let\svitem\item
\newcommand\difbox[1]{\stackengine{0pt}{\color{white}\rule{5ex}{1.15ex}}{\makeballs{#1}}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}

\newcommand\makeballs[1]{$\iftrue\makeballsA#1\fi \unskip$}
\def\makeballsA#1#2\fi{\fi
  \ifx R#1\textcolor{red}{\blacksquare}\else
  \ifx B#1\textcolor{blue!35}{\blacksquare}\fi\fi \hspace{.7em}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax \else\makeballsA#2\fi}
  
\newenvironment{benumerate}
{\renewcommand\item[1][1]{\def\difficulty{##1}\svitem}%
  \def\labelenumi{\smash{\stackunder[5pt]{\color{blue!65!black}%
  \bfseries\sffamily\theenumi}{\expandafter\difbox\expandafter{\difficulty}}}}%
  \enumerate}{\endenumerate}

\begin{document}
\large
\begin{benumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{0}
\item[RBRRBR] \lipsum[11]
\item[RRR] \lipsum[39]
\item[BRRRB] \lipsum[13]
\end{benumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here I abstracted away `\makeballs` to a separate macro so it may be reused elsewhere without having to pay attention to the actual working details.

Also, `\hspace` (unstarred) or `\hskip` must be used here since `\hspace*` adds intervening boxes.

---

**Addendum**: another way is to add the space only if there is a next iteration.

```
\newcommand\makeballs[1]{$\iftrue\makeballsA#1\fi$}
\def\makeballsA#1#2\fi{\fi
  \ifx R#1\textcolor{red}{\blacksquare}\else
  \ifx B#1\textcolor{blue!35}{\blacksquare}\fi\fi
  \ifx\relax#2\relax \else\hspace{.7em}\makeballsA#2\fi}
```